# How to show that the sequence $x_n=\sqrt{n-1}$ is not bounded above?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to formally show that $X_n$ = $\sqrt{n-1}$ is not bounded above.

I am new to this, so here is my shot at it:

$\forall$ $x \in X_n$ $\exists M : $ $x < M$

$X_{M-1} = \sqrt{M-1}$  Which is not a lower bound

$X_{M^2 +1} = \sqrt{M^2} = M$    Which is an upper bound

$X_{M^2 + 2} = \sqrt{M^2 + 1}$

$ X_{M^2 +1} \leq X_{M^2 + 2}$

By the Archimedean property of real numbers, 
$\forall M \in \Re$ $\exists k > M$

Then for any upper bound M, there exists a larger index k such that $X_k > X_M$

I know this is a very simple problem, I am just trying to prove unboundedness without the use of limits.

Thanks for the help

Comment: $X_{n^2-1}=\sqrt{(n^2-1)+1}=\sqrt{n^2}=n$

Comment: The sequence should read: $X_n = \sqrt{n-1}$

Comment: In that case $X_{n^2+1}=n$, and that, together with the Archimedean property, is all that you need: given any $x\in\Bbb R$, there is a positive integer $n\ge x$, and $X_{n^2+1}=n\ge x$. Therefore the sequence is unbounded about. (It’s clearly bounded below by $0$.) By the way, you probably want **un**bounded in the title.

Comment: That's what I thought. Sometimes I second guess the completeness of my solutions. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: The function $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is unbounded, in other words $\lim \sqrt x=\infty$. Then the function $g(n)=\sqrt{n-1}$ is unbounded.

Comment: @Masacroso, the above question was not at all related to functions.